# Extracting data from Tally using ODBC to Excel

Tags: excel, odbc, tally

As mentioned in many [help files](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/Tally.ERP9/Data_Management/DM_TE9_Outward_Connectivity.htm), I need to open excel then get external data "From Other Sources" and select "From Microsoft Query".

In the list I should see "TallyODBC_9000" or a variation of this. But I don't see this. I have checked everything including ensuring that the server is running. I have also tried to add an ODBC server unsuccessfully.

Any help in connecting to Tally ODBC from Excel will be much appreciated.

I am using - Tally 6.4.8 & Excel 2016

Comment: Did you read this link? https://www.caclubindia.com/articles/linking-tally-with-excel-steps-advance-excel--22643.asp.  As it looks to have some additional steps that need to be completed in Tally before you can connect Excel to Tally.

Comment: Yes I did. I have also read all articles on first 2 pages of google search (including the one you linked) and tried a few other things as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way i could finally find to export data to excel format was to use the inbuilt sql query in tally.